# jQuery animate height of Google Map container

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-animate

I have a map container DIV. Lets call it #mapcontainer.

I animate its height with jQuery:

```
$("#mapcontainer").animate({height: +=200px}, 500);
```

I know that if a map container is resized google maps needs to be triggered to be resized using:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Now the obvious thing is to do this in the callback of animate:

```
$("#mapcontainer").animate({height: +=200px}, 500, "linear", function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

But this doesn't look smooth and the map just juts to the hight after the animation has completed.

Is there anyway that the map can be resizing as the animation is running so the map transitions smoothly?

Comment: You trigger the event after the animation is complete. It's not a good solution but maybe you can use setInterval and trig the event every 1ms when the animation is running. Maybe it it will lag, and as I said its not a best-practies solution.

Comment: @SimonEdström - Thanks I will give this a go. I will let you know how this goes

Comment: @SimonEdström - take a look at http://jsbin.com/obitud/3/edit I was able to set the update to 100 milliseconds instead so not to lag. You have a bit of leeway anyway as part of the tiles are already below the fold.

Comment: I think it looks good. What do you mean by the last sentence, I don't really get it?

Comment: @SimonEdström - GMaps are made up of image squares and some part of the image is already loaded outside of the div viewport. So when you start expanding you reveal the rest of the tile. The resize event basically loads in more tiles if needed to fill the div viewport. Play with the JS code and remove the trigger and see for yourself what is already loaded

Comment: Oh ok, I understand what you mean. That is good for this issue ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trigger the event after the animation is complete and I think it's the issue.

It's not a good solution but maybe you can use setInterval and trig the event every 1ms when the animation is running. Maybe it it will lag, and as I said its not a best-practies solution.

```
var timer;

timer = setInterval(function(){ google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')}, 100);
$("#mapcontainer").animate({height: +=200px}, 500, "linear", function(){
    timerMap = clearInterval(timer);
});
```