# Click to expand button with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a Google map that is 100% width but 25% height, I want to be able to click a button which adjusts the height to 100%... how can I do this and add some way of easing it so it doesn't just jump to 100%?

The button would need to say "click to expand" and once clicked it should change to "click to contract" - with the jquery then working in reverse.

Comment: You can use the animate method of jquery. But what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JQuery and its animate function. 
see this jsfiddle for a quick sample

http://jsfiddle.net/z5aXz/

```
    $("#go").click(function(){
    $("#block").animate({
        height: "100px"
     }, 1500 );
    });
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to work with the height being 100%, it works with px.

Comment: Can this be of any help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128226/problem-using-jquery-to-animate-div-to-100-height

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `$.animate(...)` [function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

You will call it in the `click()` handler of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Same story:
[Animate Gmap resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210260/jquery-animate-height-of-google-map-container)

```
var timer;

    timer = setInterval(function(){ google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')}, 100);
    $("#mapcontainer").animate({height: +=200px}, 500, "linear", function(){
        timerMap = clearInterval(timer);
    });
```